# How to tell if there's been changes to parts for a car model from different years? (ex: 2011, 2012 & 2013)

Tags: parts

My car was in an accident, so now I am looking to replace the damaged parts (front bumper, fender, door, headlight assembly).

My car is a 2013 model but there are options from other years like 2012, 2011, 2010. Visually I was not able to find any differences from the images. Is there a way to be certain if the parts will fit to my 2013 model or if there are any differences between the parts from different years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parts are usually listed as being correct for a range of vin numbers - from this one to that one.

So the bumper may be correct from 74567 up to 95678 as an example.

This is more accurate than just a date - some manufacturers produce many cars in one day of 24 hours...

Comment: Thanks for that info. Is there any publicly available information where I can cross check if a bumper that I am looking to purchase fits the correct range of vin numbers?

Comment: From the supplier of the bumper normally... I find parts I look at will say from X to Y as relevant.